# Troubles with BottomNavigationBar // Extra pages

Tags: flutter, navigation, navigation-drawer, navigationbar, flutter-bottomnavigation

I'm using the BottomNavigationBar + the BottomNavigationBarItem widget to switch through pages within one scaffold. My problem:

I'm also using a Drawer to give navigation options. I was able to use the same list of pages I use with the bottom navigation bar in the drawer. That works. But: I now want to use the drawer to offer more pages than in the bottom bar and as soon as I want to set the index to those pages, the BottomNavigationBar throws an error:

> 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar.dart': Failed
> assertion: line 192 pos 15: '0 <= currentIndex && currentIndex <
> items.length': is not true.

What seems to happen is that the BottomNavigationBar is keeping me from using more pages than connected to the Bottom Bar. Is there anay way around this? I don't want more than 4 symbols in the bottom bar, but I want 5 pages; and if possible all of them in the same Scaffold. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For making this you need to manage variables logically. Here is a complete example.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        switch (settings.name) {
          case HomePage.route:
            return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Scaffold(
                      body: Container(
                        color: Colors.amber,
                        child: const Text("home"),
                      ),
                    ),
                settings: const RouteSettings(name: HomePage.route));
        }
      },
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String route = "/home";

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _pageIndex = 0;
  int _drawerIndex = 0;
  List<int> screenStack = [0];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("page $_pageIndex"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            if (screenStack.length > 1) {
              setState(() {
                screenStack.removeLast();
                _pageIndex = screenStack[screenStack.length - 1];
              });
              return false;
            }
            return true;
          },
          child: IndexedStack(
            index: (_drawerIndex < _pageIndex) ? _pageIndex : _drawerIndex,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => const Scaffold(
                                        body: Center(
                                          child: Text("DetailsPage"),
                                        ),
                                      )));
                        },
                        child: const Text("navigate"),
                      ),
                      const Text('Home'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: const Center(child: Text('Business')),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: const Center(child: Text('Technology')),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                child: const Center(child: Text('Education')),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.deepOrange,
                child: const Center(child: Text('Others')),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  setState(
                    () {
                      _pageIndex = 0;
                      _drawerIndex = _pageIndex;
                      if (_pageIndex == 0) {
                        screenStack = [0];
                      } else if (!screenStack.contains(_pageIndex)) {
                        screenStack.add(_pageIndex);
                      }
                    },
                  );
                },
                title: const Text("Home"),
              ),
              ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  setState(
                    () {
                      _pageIndex = 1;
                      _drawerIndex = _pageIndex;
                      if (_pageIndex == 0) {
                        screenStack = [0];
                      } else if (!screenStack.contains(_pageIndex)) {
                        screenStack.add(_pageIndex);
                      }
                    },
                  );
                },
                title: const Text("Business"),
              ),
              ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  setState(
                    () {
                      _pageIndex = 2;
                      _drawerIndex = _pageIndex;
                      if (_pageIndex == 0) {
                        screenStack = [0];
                      } else if (!screenStack.contains(_pageIndex)) {
                        screenStack.add(_pageIndex);
                      }
                    },
                  );
                },
                title: const Text("Technology"),
              ),
              ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  setState(
                    () {
                      _pageIndex = 3;
                      _drawerIndex = _pageIndex;
                      if (_pageIndex == 0) {
                        screenStack = [0];
                      } else if (!screenStack.contains(_pageIndex)) {
                        screenStack.add(_pageIndex);
                      }
                    },
                  );
                },
                title: const Text("Education"),
              ),
              ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  setState(
                    () {
                      _drawerIndex = 4;
                    },
                  );
                },
                title: const Text("Others"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.computer),
            label: 'Technology',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.book),
            label: 'Education',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _pageIndex,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(
            () {
              _pageIndex = index;
              _drawerIndex = _pageIndex;
              if (_pageIndex == 0) {
                screenStack = [0];
              } else if (!screenStack.contains(_pageIndex)) {
                screenStack.add(_pageIndex);
              }
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class DetailRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  late TextEditingController? textEditingController;
  int? index;

  DetailRoute({Key? key, this.textEditingController, this.index})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! I'll see if I can apply it in my code. It does look completely different from my current approach though.  And I'm still a beginner having trouble reading pure code. Can you give ne a short primer on what the idea behind this is? It make it easier to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach-

```
class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  int pageIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> pageList = <Widget>[Home(), Profile(), Setting()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: pageList[pageIndex],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            fixedColor: Colors.redAccent[400],
            currentIndex: pageIndex,
            onTap: (value) {
              setState(() {
                pageIndex = value;
              });
            },
            // type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  activeIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.home,
                    color: AppColors.black,
                  ),
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.home,
                    color: AppColors.grey,
                  ),
                  label: ""),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  activeIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    color: AppColors.black,
                  ),
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    color: AppColors.grey,
                  ),
                  label: ""),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  activeIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.settings,
                    color: AppColors.black,
                  ),
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.settings,
                    color: AppColors.grey,
                  ),
                  label: ""),
            ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is what I'm doing. Now imagine I want to have more Widegts in *pageList* and set **pageIndex** to their index not by clicking on a NavigationBarItem, but by using a function *setIndex(index)* and using it from somwhere else (e.g. a Drawer). The BottomNavigationBar realizes that the index is larger than the list of BottomNavgationBarItems and gives me the error message from my op. As long as I stay within the range of the BottomNavigationBar, my solution already works.